# observable inside subscribe the function is not working i.e function inside subscribe is not called as navigate is not working

Tags: angular

## router.navigate not called as subscribe function is not get inside the subscribe#

I used http registeruser and mapped it in auth.service but when I subscribe it  this.authService.registeruser(user).subscribe((data) the function inside subscribe is not called even if I used console.log("message") ,message is also not display

### register.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
//import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css'],
  providers:[AuthService]
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    
  name:String;
  username:String;
  email:String;
  password:String;
  designation:String;

  constructor(
    private authService:AuthService,
    private _router:Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
  }
  
  onRegisterSubmit(){
    const user={
      name:this.name,
      email:this.email,
      username:this.username,
      designation:this.designation,
      password:this.password
    }
   
    
  
    this.authService.registeruser(user).subscribe((data)=>{
      if(data.success){
        console.log("success");
        this._router.navigate(['login']);
      }
     
    });


  }


}

###auth.service.ts###

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{Http,Headers} from '@angular/http';

 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
   user:any
  constructor(private http:Http) { }

 
  registeruser(user){
    var headers=new Headers();
    console.log(headers);
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:4100/register',user,{headers:headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
  }


}
```

Comment: Can you try if(data) instead of if(data.success) in the subscribe?

Comment: What does `data` contain? Perhaps you are triggering an error. What does the network tab show for the call?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add '/'

```
  this._router.navigate(['/login']);
```

Comment: problem in not in navigate , the problem is that it dont even print success msg in console i think there is some error in subscribe ,which i cannot able to find